# A Radon measure on $G$ being left-invariant on a dense subgroup $H \subset G$ is a Haar measure on $G$.

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, $H$ a dense subgroup, and $μ$ a [Radon
measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure) on $G$ such that $μ(hA) = μ(A)$ holds for every measurable set $A ⊂ G$ and
every $h ∈ H$. Show that $μ$ is a (*left-invariant*) [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure).

Any help with this is appreciated !

Comment: with the $H$ invariant and locally finite property, inner regular and outer regular becomes a useless detail

Answer (score 3):

This is Exercise 1.6 in *Principles of Harmonic Analysis* by Deitmar & Echterhoff.

> Let $G$ be a locally compact group, let $H \subset G$ be a dense subgroup, and let $\mu_G$ be a Radon measure on $G$ such that $\mu_G (h A) = \mu_G(A)$ whenever $A \subset G$ is measurable and $h \in H$. Since $H$ is dense in $G$, there exists for all $g \in G$ a net $(h_j)_{j \in J} \subset H$ with $h_j \to g$. The continuity of the map $G \to [0, \infty], \;\; x \mapsto \mu_G (x A)$ implies next that
>   $$ \mu_G (A) - \mu_G (gA) = \mu_G (A) - \lim_j \mu_G (h_j A) = 0, $$
>   and hence $\mu_G (A) = \mu_G (gA)$ for all $g \in G$. Thus $\mu_G$ is a Haar measure on $G$.

Comment: Proving that $x\mapsto \mu_G(xA)$ is continuous is a nontrivial step, and is really the heart of the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to show that $\mu_G(A)=\sup\{\mu_G(K)|K\subseteq A, compact\}$. This helps us because it reduces the problem to showing that $\mu_G(gK)=\mu_G(K)$ holds for all $K\subseteq G$ compact.

First of all note that $\mu_G(K)<\infty$ holds. To see this use that $\mu_G$ is locally finite and therefore there exists a closed unit neighborhood $U$ of finite measure. Then the density of $H$ in $G$ implies that $K\subseteq \bigcup_{h\in H} hU$. Since this is an open covering, one obtains $h_1,\dots,h_n\in H$ such that $K\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^n h_iU$ and thus

\begin{align*}
\mu_G(K)\leq\mu_G\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n h_iU\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_G(h_iU)=n\mu_G(U)<\infty.
\end{align*}

Next we want to show that $g\mapsto \mu_G(K)$ is continuous for every $K\subseteq G$ compact. Therefore for fixed $g_0\in G$ and a compact neighborhood $V$ of $g_0$, it follows that $\textbf{1}_{gK}\leq\textbf{1}_{VK}$ and thus
\begin{align*}
V\ni g\mapsto\mu_G(gK)=\int_{G}\textbf{1}_{gK}(x)d\mu_G(x)
\end{align*}
is continuous by Lebesgue's theorem on dominated convergence as $VK$ is compact and thus $\mathbf{1}_{VK}$ integrable.

Since $g\mapsto\mu_G(gK)$ is continuous in every neighborhood the assertion follows from the density of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but how is the dominated convergence theorem applicable here? The theorem is only for sequences but here we have to consider nets to prove continuity.